# reasons for emulator not opening after installing android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed android in eclipse, everything is fine but after launching the AVD, emulator was not opening. At what situations it will happen? It was showing error like

```
[2012-07-19 17:09:04 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: path might changed. see your eclipse preference.

Comment: I checked in the preferences tab also. It was showing same(exactly where is android sdk )

Comment: Just reset adb, it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check out this -
```

["The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072706/the-connection-to-adb-is-down-and-a-severe-error-has-occured)

as well

[Error: "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r)

Or you can do one thing give correct path of android-sdk-windows.

Comment: Than problem must be giving correct path of android-sdk-windows.Have you done this??

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the emulator button in eclipse, too.
Some times it just wont't fire the emulator up. I actually have no guess why this is (maybe it opens up in another dimension where you can't see it :P).
I worket around this issue by simply not using the button ;).
I start the emulator manually.
On linux after creating your emulator configurations you can start an emulator from the command line.

In your Android SDK folder there is a subfolder "tools".
You can run the "emulator" program and give it the name of the AVD configuration as first argument.

emulator @My_AVD_Configuration_Name

You have to put the @ token in front of the name.
Then you can install your APK file by using the "adb" program.
The "adb" program is in the "platform-tools" subfolder in your Android SDK.
Just write.

adb install -r MyAndroidApp.apk

I hope this helps a bit :)

Comment: I opened emulator in tools folder, but it was automatically closed.

Comment: when i started to open the emulator it was not showing in the task manager

Comment: nw i'm getting this type of messahe, still emulator was not opening.
 [2012-07-20 12:19:07 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2012-07-20 12:19:07 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-20 12:19:07 - FirstApp] Performing com.zen.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-07-20 12:19:07 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avd'
[2012-07-20 12:19:07 - FirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd'