# Adb connection Error persists

Tags: android, adb, ddms

Yes I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r) link and it worked fine. But again in few minutes (sometimes immediately after resetting adb) it shows `Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` in DDMS. There are many causes to this error, starting an emulator, when I connect my device to PC and (the hilarious is) when I connect iPod to my PC for charging purpose.

Though it work by resetting adb, logcat is not updating with the current execution.

It was running good previously and am using Windows 7 OS.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Have you updated/upgraded/changed your firewall by any chance?

Comment: @AndroidEve No chance. And no one can access my PC.

Comment: OK, so that's not what changed in your system. *Something* must have changed in your system if it was running good previously. Are you using the emulator? or connecting to a real physical device?

Comment: @AndroidEve This might be offence to say here, but have to say as you said "Something must have changed in system". I just jailbreak my iPod and installed such softwares to install apps on it & obviously iTunes. Am using both one emulator &  one device simultaneously for debugging.