# Can't run app on my phone for testing: Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android

I am trying to run an app that I made on my phone to test, but my device does not come up in the Devices tab in DDMS. Below is the error I get when I "Reset adb" in DDMS for android in eclipse. I've googled this error and issue for hours but none of the solutions have worked for me like resetting the adb and killing the processes. I don't know if this matters, but I am using a HTC One. The error is:

```
[2013-11-22 01:59:03 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2013-11-22 01:59:04 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

Please help!

Comment: are you sure that debugging is on

Comment: @Arju Yes it is, and so is developer options.

Comment: is the `USB debugging` in your device ticked and the `Unknown sources` in security tab ticked too?

Comment: @Coderji Yes they are.

Comment: I think the same meeting is here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r

Comment: I used to have this problem with my HTC one in windows 8, what windows you are using?

Comment: @Arju I've already read those posts, and those solutions did not fix my issue

Comment: @Coderji I am running in windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution to my own problem after much troubleshooting.

Just go to Device Manager and under the Action tab, click on Update Driver Software and it will automatically fix the problem for you by adding "Android USB Devices" to your Device Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will work with you, I had same problem with my HTC ONE in windows 8 so what I did is that I download  the HTC drivers for windows 8, now the same driver works for windows 7 so follow this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2232799) it has detailed steps on how to do it. please give me a feedback whether it worked or not.

Comment: I run into a problem at step 4 where I can't locate "Other Devices" in my "Device Manager" because there is no tab for "Other Devices"

Comment: I found the solution, I just posted the answer. xD Thanks for trying to help though. I appreciate you trying to help me out.

Comment: Happy programming! :D

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with HTC devices not being recognized by DDMS. 90% of the time i solved it by installing HTC software (i think it was HTC sync, but im not sure).

Also, make sure you installed USB debug tools from Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to consider Hardware failure!

```
Adb connection Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Facing the same problem I found out the **USB cable** I was using was slightly damaged, enough to cause constant connection failure. I didn't have problems accessing data on the phone, so it took me a while to find it out.

I replaced the cable and it works fine now!

Comment: Same USB cable worked (shows tags in the log cat) on other Lenovo phones but not on my Lenovo phone.