# I/O Error Connection refused android studio

Tags: android, macos

WhenI run a project in android studio, I get this error - **I/O Error: Connection refused**

### The emulator starts fine but doesn't pull in/reflect my project

```
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device is online: emulator-5554
Target device: Nexus4 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
local path: /Users/martinsjolte/AndroidStudioProjects/FirstAPP1/Firstapp1/build/apk/Firstapp1-debug-unaligned.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/dk.first.Firstapp1
Installing dk.first.Firstapp1
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/dk.first.Firstapp1"
Device disconnected: emulator-5554

Launching application: dk.first.Firstapp1/dk.first.Firstapp1.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "dk.first.Firstapp1/dk.first.Firstapp1.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

### **I/O Error: Connection refused**

My platform is a mac osx ver.12.9.1

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I don't know if i got "the" answer. but here is how I've solved the same issue on my environnement ( Windows 8/Android Studio, but same error with ADT or eclipse) :

### Context of my issues :

I've got an Asus PC, and with all the application suite installed by default.
So I've found that one of this Asus app ( currently "Asus sync") was using adb and in fact, it was taking control of the emulator over my adb in the AndroidSDK directory.

---

### How to fix as a PC user :

Go to **Task manager** ( right click on task bar) , and look for "**adb.exe**" . Then right click on it and select "Open the directory". This will bring you to the responding adb. In my case it was Asus Sync, so I just had to unistall this software and everything works fine !

---

### How to fix as a Mac user :

Go to **Activity Monitor** (/Applications/Utilities/), and look for "**adb**". Then try to kill the process. Then look if it solve your "Connection refused" in Android studio/ADT or eclipse

---

### If still not working you can try :

- Start a emulator ( with your **AVD manager**)
- when finished loading,  Open **DDMS panel** (in android studio : Menu Tools > Android > Monitors DDMS)
- Look if you see your current running android emulator ( listed on the **Device** panel)
- See if this line is kind of "flashing" ( connect/disconnect).
- If so, you have probably a other adb instance running in conflict
- If not, you can [restart adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r) or reinstall your SDK

Hope this could help someone !

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs when Android Debug Bridge aka ADB is not responding to the request from Android Studio. I killed the process adb.exe and started it again. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using a real device :**

Just reconnect your device, make sure your cable are workable and you installed the proper drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my problem fixed by restarting the android-studio. Hope, that will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked(after I tried the above points mentioned by others):

1. I tried debugging/running anther application. It was okay. So this pointed me to the direction that the current application has some problem
2. if (point 1 == true) {I uninstalled the application from my phone manually }

Then re-make/rebuild the application and debug/run worked