# Adb daemon doesn't start automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Since upgrading to Android Studio Bumblebee, the adb demon doesn't start automatically when launching AS. I have to manually start it with `adb start-server` every time I launch AS in order to run/debug projects. That wasn't the case before the upgrade.

The setting is set to automatically start:

[image]

Is there a way to start it automatically when launching Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r/#answer-70941381). Resolved by disabling `adb mDNS for wireless debugging`:

`Android Studio > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Untick "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging"`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way too but i helped me with a simple batch file.
The code of this file is:

C:\Users\ 'user'\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server

start /d "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" studio64.exe

Of course you have to look if the path is the same on your computer.
If you save this code in a txt-file and change the ending from ".txt" to ".bat" it should work. At least it does at my computer.

I hope that could help because in my case it works now... Isn't a quite beautiful solution but at least it works.

Comment: Thanks. I got this resolved by disabling `adb mDNS for wireless debugging`; please have a look at my answer.