# Getting weird error while running application into emulator or device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

Below error encountered whenever I tried to run application into emulator or device.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'E:\ParentDirectory\Projests\WorkSpace\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Connection refused: connect'
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I tried to clean and re-build the project even tried to clear cache and restart the Android studio but no luck.

Comment: Can you please check this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941381/5674223

Comment: @UkFLSUI That solved my problem in Bumblebee. Thanks!
What about you RobinHood ?